# Python - catch exception within exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have this exception defined:

```
class ArgumentsException(Exception):
    """Exception that is raised when incorrect arguments are used."""

    pass
```

Now I run my test where I run my program through `sh` package. And when it raises this expected exception, `sh` catches that exception itself and then reraises his own exception. Is there a way for me to check if my original exception was raised somehow?

For example when I run this code (this code is expected to raise that exception):

```
sh.python3(
  self.main_py_path,
  self.live_cfg_path,
  self.workflow_cfg_path)
```

I get this exception instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oerp/src/devops-tools/tests/test_main.py", line 153, in test_full_workflow_1
    self.workflow_cfg_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh.py", line 1427, in __call__
    return RunningCommand(cmd, call_args, stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh.py", line 774, in __init__
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 
  RAN: /usr/bin/python3 /home/oerp/src/devops-tools/main.py /home/oerp/src/devops-tools/tests/configs/__live__.py /home/oerp/src/devops-tools/tests/configs/__workflow__.py

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oerp/src/devops-tools/main.py", line 204, in <module>
    state = _get_state(args.state, ignore_state=args.ignore_state)
  File "/home/oerp/src/devops-tools/main.py", line 68, in _get_state
    "__state__.py file must be provided if --ignore-state flag "
exceptions.ArgumentsException: __state__.py file must be provided if --ignore-state flag is not used.
```

Well I can do something like:

`self.assertTrue('ArgumentsException' in str(e.stderr))`

But maybe there is more elegant way to check my exception?

Comment: Odd that you get cut off after `sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:`, [when I tested it](https://repl.it/repls/GlamorousHuskyInternalcommand) I get a full traceback including the original exception.

Comment: @Idlehands sorry I confused you, yes I do get full traceback too (did not copy full traceback before). I updated the question. Though the question still remains, how can I catch that exception instead of fishing for "string" that represents my exception?

Comment: In that case, parsing the byte string might be the most sensible solution unfortunately.  As an alternative you can do `e.stderr.splitlines()[-1].split(b':', 1)[0]` instead to get you the exact Exception that occurred, but it'll of course still be a byte string instead of an Exception object.  The difficulty lies with `sh` package wrapping the errors within its own Exception as a byte string instead of the Exception object, so there was no way for you to retrieve it once you ran the line `sh.python3()`.

Comment: You *could* `eval(e.stderr.splitlines()[-1].split(b':', 1)[0])` which should give you the class `ArgumentsException`... but I couldn't recommend such a volatile method.

Comment: @Idlehands thanks for ideas, anyway:)